# Custom Jersey ExceptionMapper in Spring Boot with kotlin

Tags: spring-boot, jersey, jax-rs, kotlin

I have trouble registering a custom ExceptionMapper with Spring Boot and Kotlin.

```
@Configuration
@ApplicationPath("/api")
class JerseyConfig : ResourceConfig() {
    init {

                register(JWTAuthExceptionMapper::class.java)
                .register(GsonProvider::class.java)
                .register(PingResource::class.java)
                .register(AuthResource::class.java)

    }
}
```

The mapper:

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response
import javax.ws.rs.ext.ExceptionMapper
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider

@Provider
@Component
class JWTAuthExceptionMapper() : ExceptionMapper<JWTAuthException> {

    override fun toResponse(exception: JWTAuthException?): Response {
        return Response.status(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED).entity(exception?.message).build()
    }
}
```

The toResponse method is not called on JWTAuthException.

Do I miss something?

Comment: ...Did you find any solution for this ?